Understanding unapply of case classes
I have this simple code:
❯ scala-cli -j system -S 3.3.4
Welcome to Scala 3.3.4 (21.0.5, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
                                                                                                                                  
scala> case class Point(x:Int,y:Int)
// defined case class Point
                                                                                                                                  
scala> val p = Point(1,2)
val p: Point = Point(1,2)
                                                                                                                                  
scala> Point.unapply(p)
val res0: Point = Point(1,2)


After having read this and the official doc, I expect that Point.unapply() to return Option[(Int, Int)] instead of being an identity function. In my example to return Some((1, 2)).
What am I missing in my reasoning?

Empirically, I've discovered a different behaviour in Scala 3.X vs Scala 2.13
❯ scala-cli -j system -S 2.13.15
Downloading Scala 2.13.15 bridge
Welcome to Scala 2.13.15 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 21.0.5).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> case class Point(x:Int,y:Int)
class Point

scala> val p = Point(1,2)
     | 
val p: Point = Point(1,2)

scala> Point.unapply(p)
val res0: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1,2))

Explanation:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/pattern-matching.html

Could you expand a bit on the "explanation", the link you posted contains quite a bunch of information.

@GaëlJ, I haven't read it carefully because it is a little overwhelming, but the important point is that something has been changed related to my experiment.

Scala 2's unapply returned either a Boolean (match without extraction) or Option of value/tuple (match with extraction, one could use Some to make it match always). Scala 3 additionally allows returning anything tuple-like (having fields _1, _2, _3, ...) so for cases when something should be always matched it might not allocate (case classes have _1, _2, _3, ... in Scala 3, so their unapply is basically identity function which just checks that input is of the right type).

Thanks @MateuszKubuszok, I now understand.
